# How to make animation only run when open or restart app in adnroid studio

Tags: java, android, animation

I have a big program for the end of year project, in which in the welcome interface of the application I put in a few animations, bundle it into an animation() function and put it in onCreate. The problem here is that it won't stop when I move from the 2nd Activity to the first with Intent, it keeps running non-stop even though the Activity lifecycle is onCreate called only once. So the question I want to ask is how can we make animation() only run when the app opens or restarts.

Here is the simple example of code that i just create to try fix this problem.

Activity 1

```
    package com.example.stopanimation;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView view;
    Button button;
    boolean isFirstTime = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        view = findViewById(R.id.text);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        if (isFirstTime) {
            animation();
            isFirstTime = false;
        }

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void animation(){
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.alpha);
        Animation animatio = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.alpha);
        view.startAnimation(animation);
        button.startAnimation(animatio);
    }
    }
```

Activity 2

```
    package com.example.stopanimation;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        button = findViewById(R.id.back);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                back();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
    public void back(){
        // perform any necessary tasks before going back
        finish(); // close the current activity
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity2.this,MainActivity.class));
    }

    }
```

I did try write overridePendingTransition(0, 0); on onPaused, onResume but i did'nt seem to

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the logic of the `back()` function, which by calling `startActivity()` again causes the first activity to enter the `onCreate()` method.
The solution would be to leave it alone in a `finish()` so that the lifecycle enters the `onRestart()` and `onResume()` method directly.

```
  public void back(){
    // perform any necessary tasks before going back
    finish(); // close the current activity
  }
```